# Is there a definition for "linear" in flow transformations?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In the documentation of [`Flow.flatMapMerge`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flat-map-merge.html), there is an observation

> Note that even though this operator looks very familiar, we discourage its usage in a regular application-specific flows. Most likely, suspending operation in map operator will be sufficient and linear transformations are much easier to reason about.

I haven't been able to find an official or generally accepted definition of a "linear transformation" in this context.  I have a sense of what it means -- `map` is clearly linear, and I think `filter`, `flatMapConcat`, and `transform` are too, but I don't know about e.g. `conflate()` or `buffer(UNLIMITED)`.

Is there, somewhere, an official definition?

Comment: In this sentence, the word "linear" is used as a synonym to sequential (non-concurrent). the docs on `buffer` (and `conflate`, as its special case), explicitly mention that those operators are concurrent and break the default sequential nature of the flow.